# How to deal with unanswered questions

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, unanswered-questions

It seems there's a lot of unanswered questions with good answers, but no up votes or OP's activity. I think we could use a closing reason allowing to:

- Close an unanswered question older than 15/30/60;
- Check if the question has a not-so-bad answer;
- Check the OP's recent activity, and:

  - If recently active, ask him to comment the answer or edit the question to make it better;
  - If inactive (15/30/60 days), automatically close the question as "Probably Answered".

The unanswered list would be shorter and more accurate.

Comment: I do not understand your first line "It seems there's a lot of **unanswered** questions *with* good **answers**" What do you mean unanswered with answers?

Comment: found this in the unanswered questions list, it has an answer. http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/637/how-can-i-insert-videos-into-my-qa

Comment: OK, you are talking about questions with answers that have 0 up votes.

Comment: If I am not mistaken (someone please correct me if I am) all a question needs is at least one upvote on one or more answers to be considered answered.  So instead of closing the question, why not just upvote the answer if it seems appropriate?  I see no reason why a question should be closed just because the OP hasn't come back.

Comment: @PGmath That I believe is the case, and I 100% agree. Closing questions should not be a go-to solution :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that this is a bad idea for several reasons:

- **Closing questions should be avoided whenever possible**

I think we should be cautious of just closing questions because they are old and unanswered, even if they do/do not have an answer. I think that would be a very questionable practice.

- **You should not close a question with an answer unless it is *very* off topic or a duplicate.**

I think the only real reason to close a question with a good answer is because it is a duplicate (or of course it is well off-topic). Closing questions should not become our end-all solution.

In your question you stated

> It seems there's a lot of unanswered questions with good answers (0 up votes) but no "asker"'s activity. I think we could use a closing vote . . .

I strongly disagree, if it is a good answer, simply give it an upvote. This removes it from the unanswered queue immediately, and will solve the problem just as effectively as closing the question.

Answer (score 3):

I think I misunderstood the meaning of closing a question. I also discovered that it's possible to use the no answers filter when using the upper ***unanswered*** link.

[image]
This filter is not visible when choosing *unanswered* from ***questions*** list
[image]
So it seems my question is somehow off-topic or useless.

Comment: I had the same issue when I first looked for unanswered questions. I get what you were thinking :)